# How to simplify multiple null checks in a lambda expression

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a method, which return transactions filtered by their type or status.

```
        public IEnumerable<Transaction> GetFilteredTransactions(string type, string status)
        {
            IEnumerable<Transaction> transactions;
            if(type != null  && status != null)
            {
                transactions = Database.Transactions.GetAll().Where(x => x.Type == type && x.Status == status);
            }
            else if(type != null && status == null)
            {
                transactions = Database.Transactions.GetAll().Where(x => x.Type == type);
            }
            else if(type == null && status != null)
            {
                transactions = Database.Transactions.GetAll().Where(x => x.Status == status);
            }
            else
            {
                transactions = Database.Transactions.GetAll();
            }
            return transactions;
        }
```

I'm sure that it is possible to simplify this method, but I dont know how.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because your question kinda sounds like _code improvement_ and/or _review_ and if so may be off-topic for SO.  It _may_ be better suited for another SE site but be sure to read the relevant FAQ; and/or re-wording your question as necessary before cross-posting.  [ask].  Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

```
transactions = Database.Transactions.GetAll();

if (type != null)
{
    transactions = transactions.Where(x => x.Type == type);
}

if (status != null)
{
    transactions = transactions.Where(x => x.Status == status);
}
```

Comment: Consider improving your answer. _[Code-only answers may fall under 'Very Low Quality' ...and are candidates for deletion....We've always touted that we aren't a code factory. We are the people who teach others to fish. Code-only answers only feed a person for a day](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272/is-there-any-benefit-to-allowing-code-only-answers-while-blocking-code-only-ques)_

Comment: Thx for good answer, but. is it possible to write it in a 1 expression?

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative would be a single lambda expression:

```
x =>
(x.Type == null || x.Type == type)
&&
(x.Status == null || x.Status == status)
```

Although I'm not sure this is any more readable than your code.